# Rails validate only one enter per pair of db_columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I validate that there can only be one enter with the same `doctor_id` and `patient_id`? (a patient can only recommend a doctor once)

```
class DoctorRecommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :doctor, :class_name => "User"

  validates :patient, presence: true
  validates :doctor, presence: true
  # does not work
  validates_uniqueness_of :recommend, scope: [:doctor_id, :patient_id]

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails makes this kind of validations fairly easy.

The first step is to define the validation on your model.
The [uniqueness validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) supports a `scope` option, that should contain the name of the other column you want to limit the uniqueness to (or an Array of other columns, if it's a `>=3` column scoped uniqueness).

Your mistake is to declare it with a different name (`:recommend`).
This is what you want:

```
class DoctorRecommendation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :doctor, class_name: "User"

  validates :patient, presence: true
  validates :doctor, presence: true

  validates :patient_id, uniqueness: { scope: :doctor_id }
end
```

Considering that you already have `:presence` validations for the associated models, the `:uniqueness` validation can be limited to the IDs.

This will enable the validation on the *application layer*, that is, it will be verified in your Ruby process.
Unfortunately this is not enough in a real world scenario, where you can have multiple processes/threads modify the same table at the same time.

Imagine, for example that two requests reach your servers at the same time, both to create the same `DoctorRecommendation`. If the requests are served by two server processes/threads in parallel (or close enough), there is a chance that the Rails validation will pass in both cases.
In details:

1. both servers instantiate a new unsaved model in memory, and populate its fields
2. both read from the DB, to see if the uniqueness validation passes
3. there is no record yet with that `patient_id` and `doctor_id` pair, the validation passes in both processes
4. both servers save the record, and the data is written to the the DB
5. bang. your uniqueness constraint has been violated.

For this reason you need to enforce uniqueness on the *DB layer* as well, with a unique multi-column index.
More precisely, with:

```
class AddMultiIndexToDoctorRecommendations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    # using a custom name to make sure it's below the length limit
    add_index :doctor_recommendations,
              [:patient_id, :doctor_id],
              unique: true,
              name: 'index_docrecomm_on_patient_id_and_doctor_id'
  end
end
```

This will define a `[:patient_id, :doctor_id]` index, with a unique constraint.

If you read the docs on multi column indexes (e.g. for [postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-multicolumn.html) or [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)), you'll find that the order of the columns matters. The Migration I wrote uses the right order for the validation I defined above, which means that the validation queries will be correctly optimized. Make sure to modify the index if you want to invert the validation scope.

Now, back to the example above, on point 4 both server processes will try to save the record at the same time, but one will finish a few milliseconds before the other. The second will raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` exception, that you can rescue in your code.
For example:

```
begin
  DoctorRecommendation.create(attributes)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  # ops, let's retry again, to see if we get a validation error
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a migration and add a unique index for that combination.

```
add_index :doctor_recommenations, [:doctor_id, :patient_id], :unique => true
```